# Is a good idea have a BaseController and make all controllers extend that class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, classnotfound

I need some common behaviors in all controllers. Is a good idea have a BaseController and make all controllers extend that class? If so, What is the correct way to avoid the `Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found` error.

Comment: What's the path to this `BaseController` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly a common approach.

But an [article by ZF project lead  Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://devzone.zend.com/1218/action-helpers-in-zend-framework/) explains how [action-helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) can provide the same benefits with more flexibility.

In particular, a common base controller often becomes a dumping ground for functionality that is used in multiple-but-not-all controllers, so it become overkill. Action-helpers are kind of a lazy-load alternative, invoking functionality precisely when and where you need it.

Also, the action-helper dispatch hooks - `init()`, `preDispatch()` and `postDispatch()` - allow you to automate plugin-like functionality on a *per-controller* basis.

I'd go action-helpers. But as with most things, YMMV. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

No, don't do that. Use action helpers to add functionnality to your controller. If you use a base controller, it will quickly become complicated and unsable. Action helpers allow more flexibility.

Comment: Why/How it will become complicated or unusable ?

Comment: David had explained this very well

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a good idea and a very common pattern. Check out [Subclassing the Action Controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.subclassing) section of the reference ZF manual.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is good idea.

> What is the correct way to avoid the Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found error.

You sholud read more about [Zend_Loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html), to avoid this error